# how would i center this <iframe> on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I am running a raspberrypi to have a wall calendar in my house. I want center this clock horizontally, but as it sits, it is to the far left. This code was copied from website that offers it as-is for free.

```html
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" 
style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:300px;height:75px;" 
src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=038&timezone=EST&color=red&size=300&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2019,1,1,0,0,0&Color=red"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" 
    style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:300px;height:75px;" 
    src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=038&timezone=EST&color=red&size=300&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2019,1,1,0,0,0&Color=red"></iframe>
</div>
```

You might be able to center the whole thing easily by wrapping it in a div that uses `text-align: center`.

I am using inline styles here, since I assume you don't have `.css` file to keep your styles in. If you do, it's definitely better to keep your styles in there.

Answer (score 3):

`display: block; margin: auto;` and it'll work. Remember remove `margin: 0;` in the markup.

```css
iframe.clock-frame {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="clock-frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" 
style="overflow:hidden;border:0;width:300px;height:75px;" 
src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=038&timezone=EST&color=red&size=300&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2019,1,1,0,0,0&Color=red"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish that is to enclose the iframe within a center aligned paragraph like this:

```
<p style="text-align:center">
    <iframe style="overflow: hidden; border: 0; margin: auto; padding: 0; width: 300px; height: 75px;" src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=038&amp;timezone=EST&amp;color=red&amp;size=300&amp;Title=&amp;Message=&amp;Target=&amp;From=2019,1,1,0,0,0&amp;Color=red" width="300" height="150" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, mate it works perfectly and here is a working demo containing the original snippet. https://codepen.io/petrosdeme/pen/MWYpaZJ So please remove the down vote immediately

Comment: P is not a proper container for an iframe

Answer (score 1):

wrap in a div. declare width 100% and then do text-align:center

```css
#bestPracticeToBeSpecific {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id='bestPracticeToBeSpecific'>
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" 
style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:300px;height:75px;" 
src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=038&timezone=EST&color=red&size=300&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2019,1,1,0,0,0&Color=red"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. No need for a separate CSS file. All you need to do is wrap it in a div block and specify some centering style attribute elements

```html
<div style="justify-content: center; display: flex;">
  <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" 
style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:300px;height:75px;" 
src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=038&timezone=EST&color=red&size=300&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2019,1,1,0,0,0&Color=red"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to show what you've tried so far.

Centering is achieved by using an `absolute` or `fixed` position and then by setting the `left` and `right` offset to **0**. EG:

```
#frame {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```
#frame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
}
```

`fixed` will stick the element to the center of your screen regardless of scroll.
`absolute` will center the image relative to the width and height of it's nearest relative parent, however, you cannot use the "0" offset for absolute, you need to instead fiddle with a % until it's centered.

The final solution, where adjusting the position is not an option, is to ensure that there is a width set on the parent and that we modify the margin to automatically detect the left/right size (thus centering it).

Like so:

```
<style>
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 512px;
}
#frame {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <iframe id="frame">
</div>
```

This is a very standard solution for creating a container within which to work.

Comment: You should copy the original snippet to your answer and show a working demo.